# Difficulty with ArrayLists and mouseClicked

Tags: java, arraylist, mouseclick-event

So I'm newish to Java and am currently in an Independent study after completing an AP course.  In an attempt to create a text adventure I decided to use ArrayLists to store each "StoryEvent" that a player chose and participated in.  It will make more sense when you see the code, but essentially whenever i add StoryEvent objects to my ArrayList the lists grow in size as they should.  Yet, whenever the ArrayList is referenced from the MouseClicked() method, the ArrayList somehow becomes size 0. I use a driver to call all of this, and a separate Class to create the StoryEvents but the relevant code will follow.  The issue you need to look at here and follow is eventList.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class Adventure_Chapter1 implements MouseListener
{
// storyline based strings/buttons

static String storyLineStart = ("StoryLineStart");

static String storyOptionOne = ("Assassin Option");
static String storyOptionTwo = ("Ranger Option");
static String storyOptionThree = ("Druid Option");
static String storyOptionFour = ("Wizard Option");
static String storyOptionFive = ("Paladin Option");
static String storyOptionSix = ("Berserker Option");

boolean success = true;
JTextArea storyLineDisplay = new JTextArea(storyLineStart);
JTextArea optionOne = new JTextArea(storyOptionOne);
JTextArea optionTwo = new JTextArea(storyOptionTwo);
JTextArea optionThree = new JTextArea(storyOptionThree);
JTextArea optionFour = new JTextArea(storyOptionFour);
JTextArea optionFive = new JTextArea(storyOptionFive);
JTextArea optionSix = new JTextArea(storyOptionSix);
JPanel totalGUI;
JLabel title, chapter;
JButton buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree, buttonFour, buttonFive, buttonSix;
static int choice = 1;
ArrayList<StoryEvent> currentCharacter = new ArrayList<StoryEvent>();
ArrayList<StoryEvent> eventList = new ArrayList<StoryEvent>();


public JPanel createContentPane()   {

    JLabel chapter = new JLabel ("ESCAPE FROM AGROK KEEP");
                   //creates JLabel to be the chapter title
    chapter.setSize(350, 30);
    chapter.setLocation(465, 40);
    totalGUI.add(chapter);

    //storyLineDisplay JTextArea
    storyLineDisplay.setLocation(50, 100);
    storyLineDisplay.setSize(1170, 450);
    storyLineDisplay.setVisible(true);
    storyLineDisplay.setEditable(false);
    storyLineDisplay.setLineWrap(true);
    storyLineDisplay.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    totalGUI.add(storyLineDisplay);

    JButton buttonOne = new JButton("Option One");                          //creates the buttons for a player to use and 
    buttonOne.setLocation(50, 600);                                         // JTextAreas to display options
    buttonOne.setSize(110, 50);
    buttonOne.addMouseListener(this);
    totalGUI.add(buttonOne);

    optionOne.setLocation(210, 600);
    optionOne.setSize(600,50);
    optionOne.setVisible(true);
    optionOne.setEditable(false);
    optionOne.setLineWrap(true);
    optionOne.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    totalGUI.add(optionOne);

    JButton buttonTwo = new JButton("Option Two");
    buttonTwo.setLocation(50, 660);
    buttonTwo.setSize(110, 50);
    buttonTwo.addMouseListener(this);
    totalGUI.add(buttonTwo);

    optionTwo.setLocation(210, 660);
    optionTwo.setSize(600, 50);
    optionTwo.setVisible(true);
    optionTwo.setEditable(false);
    optionTwo.setLineWrap(true);
    optionTwo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    totalGUI.add(optionTwo);

    JButton buttonThree = new JButton("Option Three");
    buttonThree.setLocation(50, 720);
    buttonThree.setSize(110, 50);
    buttonThree.addMouseListener(this);
    totalGUI.add(buttonThree);

    optionThree.setLocation(210, 720);
    optionThree.setSize(600, 50);
    optionThree.setVisible(true);
    optionThree.setEditable(false);
    optionThree.setLineWrap(true);
    optionThree.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    totalGUI.add(optionThree);

    JButton buttonFour = new JButton("Option Four");
    buttonFour.setLocation(50, 780);
    buttonFour.setSize(110, 50);
    buttonFour.addMouseListener(this);
    totalGUI.add(buttonFour);

    optionFour.setLocation(210, 780);
    optionFour.setSize(600, 50);
    optionFour.setVisible(true);
    optionFour.setLineWrap(true);
    optionFour.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    optionFour.setEditable(false);
    totalGUI.add(optionFour);

    JButton buttonFive = new JButton("Option Five");
    buttonFive.setLocation(50, 840);
    buttonFive.setSize(110, 50);
    buttonFive.addMouseListener(this);
    totalGUI.add(buttonFive);

    optionFive.setLocation(210, 840);
    optionFive.setSize(600, 50);
    optionFive.setVisible(true);
    optionFive.setEditable(false);
    optionFive.setLineWrap(true);
    optionFive.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    totalGUI.add(optionFive);

    JButton buttonSix = new JButton("Option Six");
    buttonSix.setLocation(50, 900);
    buttonSix.setSize(110, 50);
    buttonSix.addMouseListener(this);
    totalGUI.add(buttonSix);

    optionSix.setLocation(210, 900);
    optionSix.setSize(600, 50);
    optionSix.setVisible(true);
    optionSix.setEditable(false);
    optionSix.setLineWrap(true);
    optionSix.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    totalGUI.add(optionSix);

    // add stat JLabels for characters here

    return totalGUI;
}



public void initiliaze() throws FontFormatException, IOException
{
    JFrame adventureFrame = new JFrame("The Fall of Agronak");              //creates JFrame for text adventure

    Adventure_Chapter1 demo = new Adventure_Chapter1();
    adventureFrame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

    adventureFrame.setSize(1280, 1024);
    adventureFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    adventureFrame.setVisible(true);

    load();     // loads StoryEvents
    play(0);
    System.out.println("Init() eventList size: " + eventList.size());
}

private void load()
{
    //ArrayList<StoryEvent> loadList = new ArrayList<StoryEvent>();
    int x = 0;
    switch(x)
    {
    case 0:
        StoryEvent txt0 = new StoryEvent(storyLineStart, storyOptionOne, storyOptionTwo, storyOptionThree, storyOptionFour,
                storyOptionFive, storyOptionSix, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
        eventList.add(txt0); 
    case 1:
        StoryEvent assassinStart = new StoryEvent("Assassin Breaks out of Jail.", "option 1", "option2", "option3",
                "option4", "option5", "option6", 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7);
        eventList.add(assassinStart);
    }
}

public void updatePlayer()                          // to be implemented - reprint stats and check if dead
{
    System.out.println("Player Updated ");
}

public void play(int c)                                 // to be implemented
{
    storyLineDisplay.setText("testing");
    System.out.println("Play() eventList size:" + eventList.size());
    optionOne.setText(eventList.get(c).getOption1());
    optionTwo.setText(eventList.get(c).getOption2());
    optionThree.setText(eventList.get(c).getOption3());
    optionFour.setText(eventList.get(c).getOption4());
    optionFive.setText(eventList.get(c).getOption5());
    optionSix.setText(eventList.get(c).getOption6());
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource().equals(buttonOne));
    {
        if (success == true)
        {
            updatePlayer();
            System.out.println("MouseClicked eventList size: " + eventList.size());
            //currentCharacter.add(eventList.get(choice));
            //choice = eventList.get(choice).getNext1();
            play(choice);
        }
        else
        {
            updatePlayer();
            currentCharacter.add(eventList.get(choice));
            choice = currentCharacter.get(currentCharacter.size() -1).getFail1();

        }
    }

}
```

So, essentially i call initialize(), which then creates all of the GUI elements.  Then it calls load() which adds my StoryEvents to the ArrayList eventList which is the primary issue here.  The size of eventList in initialize() is 2, as well as in the play() method.  The play() method will be used later to alter the JTextAreas with the appropriate storyline options for the game.  Yet, as soon as i click a button, in this case i have only left the code for if i click buttonOne, and check the size of eventList i get 0. There is little I can do about this, and have attempted to ask co-students, previous students, and my instructor.  If anyone could explain why eventList becomes size 0, and how to fix this I would be very grateful.  You can ignore the parts about if the success boolean == true. That will be part of the game later on, but is irrelevant currently. The errors I get are IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions whenever i try to retrieve information from eventList in MouseClicked or in play().  Eclipse tells me that in play() the ArrayList is size 2, yet it gives me an error two lines later. Here is the output:

```
Play() eventList size:2
Init() eventList size: 2
Player Updated 
MouseClicked eventList size: 0
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at Adventure_Chapter1.mouseClicked(Adventure_Chapter1.java:277)
     insert further lines of errors here.
```

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would reset that list.  Maybe you're creating a new instance of the code that contains the list over and over again.  I don't see evidence of that either.  In either case, present a subset of code that shows the issue if you want more help.  This is too much code to troll through.

Comment: Yes please only post relevant sections of your code.

Comment: One more thing in your `private void load()` method you are using `switch` after done with specific case you need to use `break` other wise it will go for next available `case`.

Comment: This is a complete guess, but try creating a default constructor and add a println in there: `public Adventure_Chapter1(){System.out.println("In constructor");}`. I don't actually see anywhere in the code where you instantiate anything, but if a new object is being created somehow at some point without your knowledge, that would explain your problem.

Comment: if you follow the path of eventList - the arrayList that is giving me issues - it goes from creation at the top of the class, into the load() method, and then mouseClicked().  When i have all my code again tomorrow i can repost just those sections as its own response to this question.

Answer (score 0):

In your code I see the code

```
//currentCharacter.add(eventList.get(choice));
```

is commented. This causes nothig to be stroed in the arrayList.

Hence the code

```
currentCharacter.get(currentCharacter.size() -1)
```

throws NUllPointer Exception

Comment: its intentionally left as a comment currently. the issue is that in the load() method, the arrayList has two StoryEvent objects stored in it. these disappear later on in the MouseClicked() method.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear to me there are two issues here.  One is you are missing a void static main entry point where you 'pack' the UI and kick off the AWT event thread.  The other is how could any of this run without a 'main' ?

You need to add your panel into a JFrame object.
Go here and build a JFrame object.  Then add your panel to that 'native' container and your results should improve.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

Comment: There is a separate class being used as a driver, and there is a JFrame created in the code. The GUI isn't the issue here, but i appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the path of eventList please.

```
public class Adventure_Chapter1 implements MouseListener
{
//GUI based JObjects here

boolean success = true;
ArrayList<StoryEvent> eventList = new ArrayList<StoryEvent>();


public JPanel createContentPane()   
{
   //creates GUI
}



public void initiliaze() throws FontFormatException, IOException
{
    JFrame adventureFrame = new JFrame("The Fall of Agronak");

Adventure_Chapter1 demo = new Adventure_Chapter1();
adventureFrame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

adventureFrame.setSize(1280, 1024);
adventureFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
adventureFrame.setVisible(true);

load();     // loads StoryEvents
play(0);
System.out.println("Init() eventList size: " + eventList.size());
}

private void load()
{
    //ArrayList<StoryEvent> loadList = new ArrayList<StoryEvent>();
    int x = 0;
    switch(x)
    {
    case 0:
    StoryEvent txt0 = new StoryEvent(storyLineStart, storyOptionOne, storyOptionTwo, storyOptionThree, storyOptionFour,
            storyOptionFive, storyOptionSix, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    eventList.add(txt0); 
    case 1:
    StoryEvent assassinStart = new StoryEvent("Assassin Breaks out of Jail.", "option 1", "option2", "option3",
            "option4", "option5", "option6", 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7);
    eventList.add(assassinStart);
}
}

public void updatePlayer()
{
    System.out.println("Player Updated ");
}

public void play(int c)                                 // to be implemented
{
    storyLineDisplay.setText("testing");
    System.out.println("Play() eventList size:" + eventList.size());
    optionOne.setText(eventList.get(c).getOption1());
    optionTwo.setText(eventList.get(c).getOption2());
    optionThree.setText(eventList.get(c).getOption3());
    optionFour.setText(eventList.get(c).getOption4());
    optionFive.setText(eventList.get(c).getOption5());
    optionSix.setText(eventList.get(c).getOption6());
 }

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource().equals(buttonOne));
    {
        if (success == true)
        {
            updatePlayer();
            System.out.println("MouseClicked eventList size: " + eventList.size());
            play(choice);
        }
        else
        {
            updatePlayer();
            currentCharacter.add(eventList.get(choice));
            choice = currentCharacter.get(currentCharacter.size() -1).getFail1();

        }
    }

}
```